# how to write a regex to match characters separated by 3 slashes?

Tags: python, regex

any string could be inside amongst the slashes, but there must be only 3 divisions. For instance,
Values that should match:

1. "90/90/90/9090"
2. "FDSAFDSA/90/pppppaA3/9090"

Values that should not match:

1. "90/90/90/9090/90"
2. "FDSAFDSA/90/pppppaA3/9090/90"

I am using python and the re library, I have tried lots of combination but none of them worked:

```
 bool(re.match(r'^.*\/.*\/.*\/((?!\/).)*$', "90/90/90/9090/90"))
 bool(re.match(r'^.*\/.*\/.*\/((?!/).)*$', "90/90/90/9090/90"))
 bool(re.match(r'^.*\/.*\/.*\/(?!(/)$).*$', "90/90/90/9090/90"))
 bool(re.match(r'^.*\/.*\/.*\/(/).*$', "90/90/90/90/90"))
 bool(re.match(r'^.*\/.*\/.*\/.*(\/)$', "90/90/90/90/90"))
```

Comment: Instead of ".*" try to use "[^/]*"  to make sure the "/" will not be matched

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ought to use [negated character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) :

```
^[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*$
```

`[^/]` matches any character but `/`, so we represent a string that contains three `/` and anything else around them.

In your regexes, the `.` could match anything including `/`, and while you could have approximated an equivalent of negated character classes using negative lookarounds, you didn't properly apply them to every `.` you had : `^((?!\/).)*\/((?!\/).)*\/((?!\/).)*\/((?!\/).)*$` would have worked too, although it would have been less performant.

And there's no need to escape those `/`, they aren't regex meta-characters. You might need to escape them in languages or tools that use `/` as delimiters, such as JavaScript's `/pattern/` syntax or sed's `s/search/replace/` substitutions.